# Netlogo divide world into upper and lower

Tags: netlogo

I am working in a program in Netlogo and I want to divide the world in upper-quadrant and lower-quadrant and ask turtles to move to the upper-quadrant. I have figured out how to divide the world in four quadrant from a previous question answered here, but I don't know how to divide it in two.

```
ask patches with [ pxcor <= max-pxcor and pxcor > 0  and pycor > 0]
  [
    set pcolor red
    set quadrant 1

  ]

  ask patches with [ pxcor >= min-pxcor and pxcor < 0  and pycor > 0]
  [
    set pcolor blue
    set quadrant 2
  ]

  ask patches with [ pxcor <= max-pxcor and pxcor > 0  and pycor < 0]
  [
    set pcolor green
    set quadrant 3
  ]

  ask patches with [ pxcor >= min-pxcor and pxcor < 0  and pycor < 0]
  [
    set pcolor yellow
    set quadrant 4
  ]
```

Comment: I also just want to point out that in OP’s example code, the phrase “pxcor <= max-pxcor” is unnecessary—by definition, pxcor can never be greater than max-pxcor. A turtle’s xcor may be, up to .5 greater, but not pxcor. Likewise for pycor and the min- version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that you are interested in a lower and an upper quadrant, you only need to look at y coordinates. The specific condition depends on where your world's origin (i.e. coordinates [0;0]) is.

If your world's origin is in the default position, which is the center, then do:

```
patches-own [
 quadrant 
]

to setup
  clear-all
  ask patches [
   ifelse (pycor > 0)
    [set quadrant 1]
    [set quadrant 2]
  ]
end
```

If your world's origin is in a corner (e.g. I assume bottom left corner in this case), just do:

```
patches-own [
 quadrant 
]

to setup
  clear-all
  ask patches [
   ifelse (pycor > max-pycor / 2)
    [set quadrant 1]
    [set quadrant 2]
  ]
end
```

If you don't know in advance where your world's origin will be, or if your world's origin is in a less common place than the two examples above, you can take a more generalised approach that fits any situation:

```
patches-own [
 quadrant 
]

to setup
  clear-all
  
  let y-extent (max-pycor - min-pycor + 1)
  ask patches [
   ifelse (pycor > y-extent / 2)
    [set quadrant 1]
    [set quadrant 2]
  ]
end
```

Comment: Ok I figured out what was bugging me: your y-extent is just WORLD-HEIGHT. So I think what you meant was “IF PYCOR > MIN-PYCOR + ( WORLD-HEIGHT - 1 )  / 2” more or less, unless the min and max are not both odd or both even. We’re also ignoring the fact that there’s a line of patches at zero. Are they in quad 1, quad 2, or neither?

Comment: Whoops, correct, missed that part in the third solution (also, I overlooked that a primitive reporter already existed as `world-height`!). As for the middle row of patches: I assumed it's implicit in the question that the OP knows that an odd number of rows can't perfectly split in two (unless they want a buffer zone, but that's out of the question), and so that they are happy to have this just as a way to show the approach. Because, after all, if one world needs to be perfectly halvable, I'd assume the author would adjust the world's extent accordingly beforehand... too much of an assumption?

Comment: Maybe. I tend to assume folks asking fairly simple (to us) questions probably are not familiar with the peculiarities of the NetLogo environment, such as grid squares (patches) being centered on the integers, vs normal “graph paper” grids, where grid square’s edges are on the major divisions. And the only way around is to forgo patches for square turtles and shift all one’s positional math over by .5 on both axis. Something I’d never expect from a beginner.